# Help With Taxonomy

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I have a taxonomy menu of countries on the home page.  When the user clicks on a country they are taken to the specific country page where the country flag and country related content is displayed.  I achieved this using tags in the content, view with contextual arguments and the Panel page using the taxonomy term template.

On the country page is another taxonomy menu of sub-categories, (i.e.-movies, songs, tv).  When the user clicks on one of the items I want them to be take to another Panel page that will display the specific content that is ALSO filtered by the country that they selected in step one.

I am at a lose as to how to achieve this.  Any ideas?

Comment: in first case, it uses one contextual arguments, So in 2nd case, need to surely use 2 contextual arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to somehow append the country tid as an additional filter to the menu links ( e.g theme function ) and use that as a contextual filter in the view for country + sub category.

Comment: i think your solution will work fine.